# Is it possible to setup a D-Link DIR-300 Wi-Fi router as repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater, dir-300

I have a cable modem provided by the ISP, which also is a Wi-Fi access point, but the Wi-Fi signal doesn't reach a room located in another floor of my house.

I have a D-Link DIR-300 router and I wonder if is it possible to use it as a repeater of the AP to get a stronger wifi signal. If it is possible to do it, are there any good "how-to" tutorial freely available so I can get this setup working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flash it with DD-WRT and set it up as an AP Repeater.

Here is the tutorial for flashing your router based on *Revision A*, please make sure you have the correct revision so that you do not brick your router.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR300

After you flash it with DD-WRT, here are the instructions on setting it up as an AP Repeater.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/AP_Repeater_on_DLINK_Dir-300

Comment: Link to instructions is broken :\